unnecessary bottom margin is being added to the div
In my wp site, there is a registration page. I have placed a reg form in it.
Page link -->  Reg Page
the form was placed in a div which contains class .form-contain.
.form-contain {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

<div class="form-contain">
  <form> </form>
</div>

I have not added any margin (not even margin-bottom), but extra space is appearing after the form-contain div.
why it is adding and how to remove this extra space ?
for that i have tried the following, but it was not worked.
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


Please provide a minimal reproduction of the problem.

i have provided the page link bro, pls visit it. i don't want the extra space after the div which contains form. https://famcopy.com/register/

Bro, your page includes more than just the minimal code needed to reproduce. Also, include it here, not in a link (I'm not clicking links, to be honest). You are the one who needs help fixing something, why would we spend more energy than you? The more energy/time you spend in writing your question, the more people will want to help.

an extra space is coming after the div which contains form. but i don't want it. i have tried margin-bottom: 0px !important also, but didn't worked.

Use your browser devtools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being applied and where it is coming from.

already inspected bro, but did not found any margins for that gap/extra space ..

In you style you set  '.form-contain'  to 'calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100 - 75px)' that causing the issue

that height property's value is necessary to make it form to page center. yet it is not working/hiding extra space even after removing that property also.

I found answer myself.
the .wrapper class has min-height property value as 100vh, i set it to auto.
Now problem cleared.
.wrapper {
   min-height: auto;
}

Thanks for all who put effort to give solution.
